# Incorrect results of differentiation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

Let us consider the derivative

```
D[Floor[x]*Sin[Pi*x]^2, x] // Simplify
```

> `Piecewise[{{Pi*Floor[x]*Sin[2*Pi*x], x > Floor[x]}}, Indeterminate]`

The result is not correct as the plot

```
Plot[Floor[x]*Sin[Pi*x]^2, {x, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

and

```
Limit[(Floor[2 + h]*Sin[Pi*(2 + h)]^2 - Floor[2]*Sin[Pi*2]^2)/h, h -> 0]
```

> `0`

show. It should be noticed that Wolfram|Alpha produces the same expression (see [that screen](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gqhlw11ttc1wghs/%D0%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202021-03-11%2007.08.46.png?dl=0) ). The command `Limit[D[Floor[x]*Sin[Pi*x]^2, x], x -> 2]` which results in `0` is not any workaround because the continuity of the derivative is not established. This is exercise 978 г) from the wellknown problem book on analysis by B. Demidovich and the answer there $\pi  \lfloor x\rfloor  \sin (2 \pi  x)$ is correct. The same issue with the derivatives of `RealAbs[Sin[Pi*x]^2]` and `RealAbs[Sin[Pi*x]^3]`.

Are there workarounds for all the integer values of `x`?

Comment: I'd like to notice that `ResourceFunction["IsContinuousFunction"][D[Floor[x]*Sin[Pi*x]^2, x],
  x]` produces an incorrect  answer `False` as well as `ResourceFunction["FunctionDiscontinuities"][
 D[Floor[x]*Sin[Pi*x]^2, x], x]` which results in `{{C[1] \[Element] Integers && 
   x == 2 C[1]}, {C[1] \[Element] Integers && x == 1 + 2 C[1]}}`.

Comment: `Limit[D[Floor[x]*Sin[Pi*x]^2, x], x -> 2]` How should the correct answer be?

Comment: What specifically is the issue being raised? That `D` gives `Indeterminate` at integer values? It does the same for e.g. `D[Floor[x]*Sin[Pi/3*x]^2, x]`. This is probably a good thing since for some purposes one wants to regard the derivative of a step function as zero and for others as a Dirac comb.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk: Thank you for your interest to the question. As it is written in the question, "The command `Limit[D[Floor[x]*Sin[Pi*x]^2, x], x -> 2]` which results in `0` is not any workaround because the continuity of the derivative is not established". This `0` does not imply that the derivative under consideration at $x=2$ equals $0$. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: If you look at the result of `Plot[Floor[x]*Sin[Pi/3*x]^2, {x, -3, 3}]` , you will see breaks at the integers (except the origin), so the derivatve does not exist at those points. The situation with `Floor[x]*Sin[Pi*x]^2` is different: this function is continuously differentiable on the reals, but `D[Floor[x]*Sin[Pi*x]^2, x] ` produces a wrong answer. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: Maybe this helps: `FullSimplify[D[Floor[x]*Sin[Pi/3*x]^2, x], 
 Assumptions -> {x \[Element] Integers}]` :P

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk: This results in `Indeterminate`, but the derivative under consideration exists and equals `0` at the integers: for example, see `Limit[(Floor[2 + h]*Sin[Pi*(2 + h)]^2 - Floor[2]*Sin[Pi*2]^2)/h, h -> 0]` as is written in my question. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84646/derivative-of-continuous-and-differentiable-piecewise-function-is-indeterminate

Comment: @MichaelE2: Indeed, something similar, but not a duplicate. There a piecewise function `Piecewise[{{k1 p + eps1, p <= p0 - delP},
                    {(1/2)(kmax - k1)/delP * (p-p0)^2 + kmax(p-p0) + ...), p0-delP <= p <= p0},
                    {(1/2)(k2 - kmax)/delP * (p-p0)^2 + ... ), p(0 <= p <= p0+delP},
                    {k2 p + eps2, p >= p0 + delP}}];` was considered at the boundary points  `p0`, `p0-delP`, and `p0+delP`, whereas here we deal with the derivative of  `Floor[x]*Sin[Pi*x]^2` at all the integers. Also several bugs are reported in the question under consideration.

Comment: @MichaelE2: There a problem might be caused by an incorrect syntax of `Piecewise`: `p0 <= p <= p0+delP` and `p >= p0 + delP` are the pieces and `p0+delP` belongs to two pieces simultaneously.

Comment: @MichaelE2: Last, but not least. The workarounds differ there and here.

Comment: It's not a wrong answer. It is in effect "I don't know that this happens to be zero on this measure zero subset". This is how the program works, and in this case there is good reason: the set of multipliers in that `Sin` for which Indeterminate is incomplete is also measure zero (which was sort of the point of my example) . One should get used to such things, if one wishes to use it productively.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: In your first comment to my question you probably confuse the derivarive of the usual function `D[UnitStep[x], x]` which results in `Piecewise[{{Indeterminate, 
   x == 0}}, 0]` with the derivative of the generalized function `D[HeavisideTheta[x], x]` which results in the generalized function `DiracDelta[x]`. Concerning your second comment, a bug is a bug. Unfortunately, the limitations of the `D` command are not documented.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Concerning "It is in effect "I don't know that this happens to be zero on this measure zero subset" ", I'd like to recall the correct work of `D[CantorStaircase[x], x]` which fails in a delicate way.

Comment: (Heh). I'm pretty sure I did not confuse those derivatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround on my own:

```
der[x_?NumericQ] := Piecewise[{{D[Floor[x]*Sin[Pi*x]^2, x], 
x \[NotElement] 
 Integers}, {Limit[(Floor[x + h]*Sin[Pi*(x + h)]^2 - 
    Floor[x]*Sin[Pi*x]^2)/h, h -> 0, 
 Assumptions -> x \[Element] Integers], x \[Element] Integers}}]
der[2]
```

> `0`

Edit. The definition of `der` should be adjusted as follows.

```
der[x_?NumericQ] := Piecewise[{{Evaluate[D[Floor[t]*Sin[Pi*t]^2, t] /. t -> x], 
x \[NotElement] 
 Integers}, {Limit[(Floor[x + h]*Sin[Pi*(x + h)]^2 - 
    Floor[x]*Sin[Pi*x]^2)/h, h -> 0, 
 Assumptions -> x \[Element] Integers], x \[Element] Integers}}]
```

Now

```
der[2.1]
```

> `3.69316`

which is confirmed by

```
Pi*Floor[2.1]*Sin[2*Pi*2.1]
```

> `3.69316`

Comment: `FunctionDomain[]` evaluates to `x \[Element] 
  Integers || (x \[NotElement] Integers && x - Floor[x] > 0)`

Comment: UlrichNeumann (@ does not work): `FunctionDomain[der[x], x, Reals]` produces "FunctionDomain::nmet: Unable to find the domain with the available methods." and returns the input. This domain over the reals found by hand is `x \[NotElement] Integers || 
x\[Element] Integers`. It's clear this is `True`.

Comment: There is some deficiency in the definition of der[x] because `der[6.1]` produces `\!\( \*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(6.1\)]0.5729490168751488\)` not simply `0.5729490168751488`.

Answer (score 2):

Try `Derivative`

```
Derivative[1][Function[x, Floor[x] Sin[Pi*x]^2]][x]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{Floor[x] Sin[Pi*x]^2 , 
Derivative[1][Function[x, Floor[x] Sin[Pi*x]^2]][x]}, {x, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, `Derivative[1][Function[x, Floor[x] Sin[Pi*x]^2]][x]` produces `2*Pi*Cos[Pi*x]*Floor[x]*Sin[Pi*x] + 
 Piecewise[{{0, x > Floor[x]}}, 
   Indeterminate]*Sin[Pi*x]^2` .This is essentially the same as `D` does. The `Plot` command does not show removable singularities. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need. Deep regard.

Comment: The output of `Derivative[1][Function[x, Floor[x] Sin[Pi*x]^2]][x]` was added to the answer after my comment, not having  indicated the change in the edit.

Comment: `Derivative[...]`and `D[...]` both give the same result in accordance with "B. Demidovich". Perhaps it's time to change the title of your question...

Comment: UlrichNeumann(@ does not work.): Your words do not correspond to reality in view of `FunctionDomain[
 Piecewise[{{Pi*Floor[x]*Sin[2*Pi*x], x > Floor[x]}}, 
  Indeterminate], x, Reals]`, resulting in `x - Floor[x] > 0`, and `FunctionDomain[Pi*Floor[x]*Sin[2*Pi*x], x, Reals]`, resulting in `True`.